# How to flow text from DIV to DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two `DIV`s with absolute position on two sides of a `HTML` page such as ([EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GYjgT/))

```
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
```

with CSS

```
.left{
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
.right{
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Is there a way to add text to the left `DIV` and flow excess text to the right one? I am not stuck to this two `DIV`, and I'm just looking for a solution to flow excess text to another position.

**NOTE:** I hope to find a pure `CSS` solution, though, it seems to be improbable; then, I am looking for a `pure javascript` solution (not using JS libraries).

Comment: With pure CSS it's impossible :) with JS it's pretty difficult to accurately get the exact point where your text overflows

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, the new CSS3 properties do allow it and is supported by most browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=column

Comment: There is no CSS solution unless you want to use CSS columns (side-by-side). Using vanilla JS is possible, but allowing jQuery would be a lot easier for DOM-specific tasks like this.

Comment: @jeff how can you (using CSS3, which I usually dream at night `;)` ) transport the overflowed content to an (complelety) other DIV element?

Comment: Any there is no javascript solution either unless you want to write one yourself. You need to take into consideration the font, font metrics etc and not forgetting the zoom level of the browser.

Comment: as @jeff said if you're interested in font metrics a quite usual method is to use the `X` character as reference

Comment: @jeff, theoretically, you can wrap the inner contents in another DIV, then subtract letters until the inner DIV fits (by comparing the inner and outer DIV heights). Then just append the subtracted letters into another DIV.

Comment: @David I would upvote this idea!

Comment: @David and if there were images in the contents????

Comment: @jeff I guess you can do the same with nodes (including text nodes). I haven’t tested any of these ideas, just thinking out loud...

Comment: CSS regions are the solution to do this, unfortunately browser support isn't quite there yet - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions

Comment: You are probably looking for something like: http://css-tricks.com/float-center/

Answer (score 5):

[CSS Regions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-regions/) (still a 'draft', but) is aiming to fix this problem:

> The CSS regions module allows content to flow across multiple areas
>   called regions. The regions are not necessarily contiguous in the
>   document order. The CSS regions module provides an advanced content
>   flow mechanism, which can be combined with positioning schemes as
>   defined by other CSS modules such as the Multi-Column Module [CSS3COL]
>   or the Grid Layout Module [CSS3-GRID-LAYOUT] to position the regions
>   where content flows.

More info and tutorials at https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/css3-regions.html

Comment: "Current Chrome status: No longer pursuing" :-(

Answer (score 1):

Here is one for `fixed-width` approach. The gap between two columns will equal to width of main div.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GYjgT/3/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sides">The big text here.<div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

For variable width you need JS or jQuery.

**Update:**

I have used jQuery for this purpose as I have found pure JS difficult to find solution of this.

```
function setGap() {
    var width = $(".main").width();
    $(".sides").css({
        "-moz-column-gap": width + "px",
            "-webkit-column-gap": width + "px",
            "column-gap": width + "px"
    });
}
$(window).resize(setGap);
setGap();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GYjgT/4/)

**Update 1:**

```
function setGap() {
    var width = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0].offsetWidth;
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("sides")[0];
    var style = elem.getAttribute("style");
    if (typeof style != "null") {
        style =
            "-moz-column-gap:" + width + "px; -webkit-column-gap:" + width + "px; column-gap:" + width + "px";
        elem.setAttribute("style", style);
    }
    else {
        style +=
            "-moz-column-gap:" + width + "px; -webkit-column-gap:" + width + "px; column-gap:" + width + "px";
        elem.setAttribute("style", style);
    }
}
window.onresize = setGap;
setGap();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GYjgT/5/)

Comment: Still this is a workaround using **one** `DIV` , but a nice one

Comment: The OP said explicitly **without libraries** :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Well, I am just suggesting him my opinion. Yeah, I am trying to reproduce it in pure JS.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Found pure JS solution :P

Comment: Nice, but still, it's not using 2 separate DIVs :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36613/discussion-between-muhammad-talha-akbar-and-roko-c-buljan)

Answer (score 1):

so far (**2012**) It's not possible using CSS, CSS3 (with 2 separate elements)

but using **JS** You can clone the content and use `scrollTop` on the right element :

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KcsrF/4/)**

```
var d = document,
    $left  = d.getElementById('left'),
    $right = d.getElementById('right'),
    leftH  = $left.offsetHeight;

$right.innerHTML = $left.innerHTML +'<p style="height:'+ leftH +'px;" />';
$right.scrollTop = leftH;
```

As you can see I'm appending also an empty paragraph, to fix the right element need to scrollTop some amount of px

<sub>**Note:** add `overflow:hidden;` to your ID elements `#left` and `#right`</sub>

Comment: Good :) better than mine.

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar I was inspired by David's comment but found a simpler solution ;)

Comment: @jeff than the OP should not build that way web sites :)

Comment: This cuts the text off through the middle of the line, so the top half of several characters are in one div, and the bottom half are in another.  Individual characters are cut in half.  That's not a good solution at all.

Comment: @iconoclast at least the right characters are cut-off. It's on you to figure out a better solution or simply set the right font size and line-height. This is just to give you an idea.