# Break text with css (text == white space == text) float text, text breaking

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, styling

Is there a way to break a text via css so that there is a "white space" in the middle? Currently I'm solving this problem via breaking the text by hand -
but this is stupid. I know there is a function where the text can end and start in another div, but it's not supported in IE.

The  text is "one" text, but I want this white space in the middle.

This shows the styling I mean:
[image: text flowing from one div to another]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to flow text from DIV to DIV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557869/how-to-flow-text-from-div-to-div)

Comment: thanks man, but i dont want to use jquery here - i have angularjs webapp - maybe i can have a soluten there ?

Comment: Also css regions are not supported in chrome or firefox.. there is another css function wich isnt supported by IE - Maybe i stick with the pure JS version

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 column-break property in your CSS to style text. It is supported by all modern browsers including IE10/11.
Or you can try the Columnizer jQuery Plugin: http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/ 
This should work with older IE.

Comment: Thanks, but i worked with angularjs and i dont want to implement another library if not needed.

Comment: Take a look at this article http://alistapart.com/article/css3multicolumn It offers stand alone JavaScript Multi-Column parser which can do the job. It supports even IE6. There is also an update for this script supporting HTML5 elements https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn