# How to separate paragraphs in sides CSS

Tags: css

I have a text that changes if the screen is big and separate the paragraphs:

Example:

Normal:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu nulla lectus. Proin imperdiet eros odio, eget interdum elit porttitor imperdiet. Nulla ac congue ante, sed consectetur lorem.

Ut dui velit, lacinia quis vestibulum in, ullamcorper quis dolor. Etiam at dignissim enim, et rhoncus nibh. Suspendisse eget luctus nisl. Maecenas iaculis quam sit amet vulputate rhoncus.

Separated:

[image]

What I want:

I need to calculate all the paragraphs and separate in left or right.

The sequence if I have 4 paragraphs:

1 ------ 3

2 ------ 4

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/left-and-right/)

Comment: [So what have you tried?](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) Have you researched CSS [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) or [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) layouts?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18558142/4603295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS columns

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

div {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus repellendus excepturi quidem molestias officiis quibusdam maiores porro voluptates.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione dolorum est culpa. Assumenda dignissimos, commodi, quas esse facilis aspernatur cupiditate excepturi aperiam eos porro fuga necessitatibus labore atque dolor laudantium nobis eveniet
    aut!</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga est in ex quas veritatis aliquam! Nulla recusandae culpa laboriosam itaque. Eum nisi quidem aspernatur dignissimos!</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, nesciunt temporibus magni excepturi fuga expedita voluptatem amet praesentium..</p>
</div>
```